# How to get the memory size of an user generated thrift object in Go

Tags: go

I am new to Go, and trying to get the estimate size of a Thrift generated object in Go, the object has multiple level, and in the case of an member variable is an collection of pointers, I want to get the total size of pointer and the data that been pointed to. The sizeOf function won't work in this case, as it will only count the space taken by the pointer, not the actual space. What's the best way to get a good estimate of the size of the object? Ideally, I would like to breakdown the size into different fields and subfields

Here is how an example object looks like in Go

```
type Microshard struct {
    Header         *Header           `thrift:"header,1,required"`
    ValidatorStats []*ValidatorStat  `thrift:"validatorStats,2,required"`
    DataMap1       map[int64][]byte  `thrift:"dataMap1,3,required"`
    DataMap2       map[int64][]byte  `thrift:"dataMap2,4,required"`
    DataMap3       map[int64][]int64 `thrift:"dataMap3,5,required"`
    DebugInfoMap   map[string][]byte `thrift:"debugInfoMap,6,required"`
    Index          *IndexData        `thrift:"index,7"`
}
```

Comment: Please use gofmt!

Comment: Before you start going down this route please read some of these answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113751/sizeof-struct-in-go (there are some cautions to be aware of when trying to understand the size of a struct)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sizeof struct in Go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113751/sizeof-struct-in-go)

Comment: @RalphCaraveo I have read that answer, but my question is more about how to handle the case when there is an collection or pointer field involved. It would much easier if the struct only contains basic type.