# High memory consumption during method execution

Tags: go, memory, memory-management, ram

For a project I want to manually create structs for each of the approximately 50 million rows of a CSV. For this I iterate line by line through the file and append each struct to a slice. This is the dumbed down method:

```
func readCSV(filePath string) DataFrame {
    file, _ := os.Open(filePath)
    defer file.Close()
    var rows []Row
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    scanner.Scan()
    for scanner.Scan() {
        parts := strings.Split(scanner.Text(), ",")
        if len(parts) < 7 {
            continue
        }
        column1, _ := strconv.Atoi(parts[0])
        column2, _ := strconv.ParseFloat(parts[1], 32)
        column3, _ := strconv.ParseFloat(parts[2], 32)
        column4 := parts[3]
        column5, _ := strconv.ParseFloat(parts[4], 32)
        column6 := parts[5]
        column7 := parts[6]
        row := Row{
            Column1: column1,
            Column2: column2,
            Column3: column3,
            Column4: column4,
            Column5: column5,
            Column6: column6,
            Column7: column7,
        }
        rows = append(rows, row)
    }
    return DataFrame{
        Rows: rows,
    }
}
```

The resulting DataFrame has around 3 GB of memory. The problem is that RAM consumption goes through the roof during method execution and the Go process uses 15GB+ of memory, making the function unusable for my purpose. Once the slice is returned, the RAM consumption of the process drops to the expected 3GB.

The heap profile looks like this:

```
    3.26GB     5.81GB (flat, cum)   100% of Total
         .          .     62:   scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
         .          .     63:   scanner.Scan()
         .          .     64:   for scanner.Scan() {
         .     2.55GB     65:           parts := strings.Split(scanner.Text(), ",")
         .          .     66:           if len(parts) < 7 {
         .          .     67:                   continue
         .          .     68:           }
         .          .     69:           column1, _ := strconv.Atoi(parts[0])
         .          .     70:           column2, _ := strconv.ParseFloat(parts[1], 32)
         .          .     71:           column3, _ := strconv.ParseFloat(parts[2], 32)
         .          .     72:           column4 := parts[3]
         .          .     73:           column5, _ := strconv.ParseFloat(parts[4], 32)
         .          .     74:           column6 := parts[5]
         .          .     75:           column7 := parts[6]
         .          .     76:           row := Row{
         .          .     77:                   Column1: column1,
         .          .     78:                   Column2: column2,
         .          .     79:                   Column3: column3,
         .          .     80:                   Column4: column4,
         .          .     81:                   Column5: column5,
         .          .     82:                   Column6: column6,
         .          .     83:                   Column7: column7,
         .          .     84:           }
    3.26GB     3.26GB     85:           rows = append(rows, row)
         .          .     86:   }
         .          .     87:
         .          .     88:   return DataFrame{
         .          .     89:           Rows: rows,
```

I am clueless where the high RAM consumption comes from. I tried to call the garbage collector manually without success. Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Instead of a slice, consider using a List. You are probably suffering from the runtime's inability to allocate contiguous storage for the slice.

Comment: Use the file size to estimate the number of rows. Preallocate size with `rows := make([]Row, 0, estimate)`.

Comment: +1 for pre-allocating the slice as best you can. Each allocation makes a new backing array, the old array will be freed by GC, and eventually may be reclaimed by the OS. You can avoid a ton of that by starting with a large enough slice.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately it didn't change anything

Comment: @Konstantin The memory allocated at `rows = append(rows, row)` should drop significantly with a good estimate for total number of rows.  Are you saying that it didn't?

Comment: @MuffinTop Yes, I count the lines in advance, which does not take too long, and initialize the slice like `rows := make([]Row, 0, amountLines)`

Comment: have you considered stream processing ?

Comment: you could also try to make use of a csv reader rather than strings split. https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/csv/#Reader it might help.

Comment: note also that parsing the csv as you did does not handle multi line csv cells. or quoted cells.

Comment: @mh-cbon The structure is known and therefore no problem; I noticed that the RAM consumption decreases significantly if I leave out the three string columns. This makes no sense to me, because when I add up the lengths of the byte arrays, I only get about 1.5 GB

Comment: i am unsure but this can be related to https://go101.org/article/memory-leaking.html

Comment: You can use sync.Pool, to reduce the size of the slice that store all the lines, and in the declaration of rows you can use make and set the capacity to 50,000,000 to avoid the recreating on the append.

Comment: Also I think you should consider if you want all the rows stored in slice the entire time; If you can make the processing in parts and load a chunk of data at a time like 10,000 rows at a time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rows` is an array of Row structs, not pointers. Each row costs 32 bytes for the floats and integers, plus however long the strings are. With 50 million rows that can get quite large. Worse, `append` will grow `rows` by about a factor of 1.5 so it can wind up allocating a lot of extra memory, while also throwing away a lot of smaller versions which need to be garbage collected. And then `append(rows, row)` is a copy meaning more allocation and deallocation. And it must wait to be garbage collected bloating the memory usage.

This can be avoided by storing references instead. This should mean less allocations and make `rows` significantly smaller.

```
var rows []*Row
...
rows = append(rows, &row)
```

---

However, the real problem is slurping everything in at once. This is Go! We can use [channels](https://gobyexample.com/channels) and [goroutines](https://gobyexample.com/goroutines) to read concurrently a row at a time along with our processing.

CSVs are deceptively tricky. Go already has a CSV library, [encoding/csv](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/csv/#example_Reader), so we'll use that.

```
# A handy function to make ignoring errors a bit less laborious.
func IgnoreError(value interface{}, err error) interface{} {
    return value
}

# Its more flexible to take an io.Reader.
# It returns a channel of individual rows.
func readCSV(input io.Reader) chan Row {
    rows := make(chan Row)
    go func() {
        defer close(rows)

        # Use encoding/csv.
        # Let it reuse its backing array for each row.
        # Ignore rows with the wrong number of columns.
        reader := csv.NewReader(input)
        reader.FieldsPerRecord = 7
        reader.ReuseRecord = true

        for {
            parts, err := reader.Read()

            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            }
            if err != nil {
                continue
            }

            # Send each row down the channel.
            rows <- Row{
                Column1: IgnoreError(strconv.Atoi(parts[0])).(int),
                Column2: IgnoreError(strconv.ParseFloat(parts[1], 32)).(float64),
                Column3: IgnoreError(strconv.ParseFloat(parts[2], 32)).(float64),
                Column4: parts[3],
                Column5: IgnoreError(strconv.ParseFloat(parts[4], 32)).(float64),
                Column6: parts[5],
                Column7: parts[6],
            }
        }
    }();
    
    return rows;
}

func main() {
    file, err := os.Open("test.csv")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    
    rows := readCSV(file)
    for row := range rows {
        fmt.Println(row)
    }
}
```

Now only one row is loaded at a time. Memory usage should be constant.

Comment: just adding for those like me not friend with low levels details. compute the size of a struct: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30632126/4466350