# Bool showing size of 4 bytes in Go

Tags: go

`strict` property of type `bool` is showing 2 different sizes. Code snippets and their output are present below.

**Case 1:**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

type Encoding struct {
    encode    [64]byte
    decodeMap [256]byte
    padChar   rune
    strict bool
}

func main() {
    e := Encoding{}

    fmt.Printf("%d", unsafe.Sizeof(e))
}
```

Output: 328

Expected: Output should have been 325 (64 + 256 + 4 + 1) bytes

**Case 2:**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

type Encoding struct {
    // encode    [64]byte
    // decodeMap [256]byte
    // padChar   rune
    strict bool
}

func main() {
    e := Encoding{}

    fmt.Printf("%d", unsafe.Sizeof(e))
}
```

Output: 1

Comment: The linked *question* isn't necessarily a duplicate, but the answer to that question is more than adequate for your question as well. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/38034334/965900

Comment: @mkopriva: It is not adequate. It doesn't explain why the proper computation is `(64 + 256 + 4 + 1 + (4 - 1)) / 4 * 4 = 328`. It's not a duplicate.

Comment: Your expectations are unwarranted.

Comment: @rocka2q the question was not about "the proper computation", the title says "bool showing size of 4 bytes" which is completely bonkers because the code in the question doesn't show that at all. Then in the question itself the akser wonders  why the sizeof results aren't as he'd expected, the answer to that is memory alignment, which the originally linked duplicate explains perfectly well. You want to put in your two cents, go ahead, but don't claim the duplicate ain't adequate when it very well is (was).

Comment: The size of `bool` is `unsafe.Sizeof(false)`.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> type Encoding struct {
>     encode    [64]byte
>     decodeMap [256]byte
>     padChar   rune
>     strict    bool
> }
> ```

---

The Sizeof(bool) is one. Your computation is incorrect.

The size of a struct is the size of its component fields adjusted with padding for field alignment. The struct is aligned to its most restrictive field alignment: rune (int32) or 4 bytes. So we have:

```
64 + 256 + 4 + 1 = 325
```

The size of the struct is then adjusted with padding for array element alignment to preserve the invariant

```
Sizeof(array) = len(array) * Sizeof(struct)
```

So, for 4 byte struct alignment, rounding up to the nearest 4, we have:

```
(325 + (4 - 1)) / 4 * 4 = 328
```

---

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

type Encoding struct {
    encode    [64]byte
    decodeMap [256]byte
    padChar   rune
    strict    bool
}

type Encodings [2]Encoding

func main() {
    var e Encoding
    fmt.Printf("%d\n", unsafe.Sizeof(e))
    var es Encodings
    fmt.Printf("%d == %d * %d\n", unsafe.Sizeof(es), len(es), unsafe.Sizeof(e))

    fmt.Println()
    fmt.Println("byte", unsafe.Sizeof(byte(0)))
    fmt.Println("rune", unsafe.Sizeof(rune(0)))
    fmt.Println("bool", unsafe.Sizeof(bool(false)))
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/CZT-5v41SfL

```
328
656 == 2 * 328

byte 1
rune 4
bool 1
```

Comment: @mkopriva: It's an integer arithmetic technique to round up. I meant what I said: https://go.dev/play/p/b9h8Foy6qdH

Comment: @mkopriva: 325 rounded up to the nearest 4 is 328: https://go.dev/play/p/5Krl4CFa9Y_4